# Excel : Split multi line text into multi line columnbvn

Tags: excel

i have huge data as follows :

row A1 : 1234

row A2 : jsdfh

row A3 : dfjkgldhlf

row A4 : 3448734kjfj

row A5 : dfjgkldjfgkl

row A7 : dfjklg;dfl

row A8 : dfkgjdf;klg

can i break the data like this with a single formula or not :

Column A1 : 1234

column B1 : jsdfh

column C1 : dfjkgldhlf

Column A2 : 3448734kjfj

Column B2 : dfjgkldjfgkl

Column A3 : dfjklg;dfl

Column B3 : dfkgjdf;klg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without coding, then just copy the data in a row, 
select any empty column cell >

right click > select 'paste special'> check 'Transpose'> OK.